# How can I render data saved as Rich Text in database to a web page using QuillJS

Tags: rtf, quill

I have used QuillJS to create a rich text editor for my flask app. The data is saved as rich text and also displayed as rich text on web page. Something like this: 
`...{"attributes":{"background":"#ffffff","color":"#666666"},"insert":"Share on Facebook"},{"attributes":{"blockquote":true},"insert":"\n"},{"insert":"I agree with the report that this is a great shame on our nation...`
I have read the quilljs documentation but am not seeing what I should use to display this appropriately (Normal text but with the formattings captured). What quilljs funtion should I use?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, you say you're using Quill to edit some text and you have issue displaying not in a edit mode to other users?

If so, the best way to display this is to use again Quill in read-only mode, It won't be efficient to re-engine something to render this rich text back. Just instantiate a Quill instance in read-only mode, without toolbar, it would just seems regular HTML text for your visitors.

Hope that helps